# difference between turning angle and heading angle random walk, how to calculate the former

Tags: random-walk, angle

I would like to know which is the difference between a turning angle and a head angle, I ask this since I am trying to estimate the parameters from data in the context of a random walk. Any suggestion how can I obtain the turning angles. If the yellow path represents my data, the absolute angles are $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, and $\theta_3$? from there how can i calculate the turning angles?[image]

Comment: You want to calculate the angle at point 2), right? If so, you already have given all information you need, the triangle $\vartriangle$123 by the length of its sides...can you work with this?

Comment: yes I know that I have all the information but I have not clarity about the concept of turning angle and absolute angle inside the context of a RW, I need to understand since I need to infer the the angles distribution

Comment: For any future answers on this: could you add the definition of your 2d-random walk (it seems you don't have a unit step size)